# R: Want to check if any element of a set of words appear in a certain string

Tags: r, text-manipulation

Assuming I have a dataframe called `items`, and the first column is `ItemNames`. I'd like to go through each item in in `items$ItemNames` and check if they contain any of these words in:

`words = c("apple","Apple","Pear","pear")`

and if they do, replace the entire string with the word `"confirmed"`.

What I've tried:

I used a combination of a `for` loop and `if` statement to do it but it failed:

```
search = function(x){
    words = c("apple","Apple","Pear","pear")
    for (i in length(x)){
        if (grepl(words, x[1][i]) == TRUE){  #where x[1][i] is the individual element in the ItemNames.
            x[1][i] = "confirmed"}
    }
}
```

`search(items)`

It didn't work. Ideally, I should have all the names in `ItemNames` replaced with "confirmed" if they contain any of the elements in `words`.

Comment: Were you trying to do exact matches or just partial matches? When asking for help you should include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. I think the duplicate answers your question but if not, edit your question to make your specific problem more clear and it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

words <- c("apple", "Apple", "Pear", "pear")
pattern <- paste(words, collapse = "|")

dt <- data.frame(
  ItemNames = c("Superb apple", "Superb Pear", "Superb car"), 
  Cost = c(1, 2, 3),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

index <- str_detect(dt$ItemNames, regex(pattern))
dt[index,]$ItemNames <- "confirmed"
```